# OOXML margins - PHP SCRIPT - Export to MS Word

Tags: php, xml, ms-word, openxml

I have the following php script which exports a .doc file. I want to set specific page margins to the exported .doc file but nothing that I tried worked.

```
 /*header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; Filename=".rand().".doc");
header("Expires: 0");*/


header( 'Content-Type: application/msword' ); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=" .date("Y-m-d").".doc");  
/*
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=" .date("Y-m-d").".rtf");
*/
$html = preg_replace('%/[^\\s]+\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)%i', 'http://www.abogaciapractica.com\\0', $_POST['description']);

print "<html xmlns:v=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml\"";
print "xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\"";
print "xmlns:w=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word\"";
print "xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\">";
print "<xml>
<w:WordDocument>
<w:View>Print</w:View>
<w:DoNotHyphenateCaps/>
<w:PunctuationKerning/>
<w:DrawingGridHorizontalSpacing>9.35 pt</w:DrawingGridHorizontalSpacing>
<w:DrawingGridVerticalSpacing>9.35 pt</w:DrawingGridVerticalSpacing>
</w:WordDocument>
</xml>
";

die($html);
```

I tried the codes that are in the following links and had no success, the page margins remained the same.

http://officeopenxml.com/WPSectionPgMar.php

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats

Thanks in advance for your time.

---

For future references I Update the post with the alternative solution I found using PHPword library.

```
    $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

$section = $phpWord->addSection(
  array('paperSize' => 'Legal', 'marginLeft' => 2834.645669291, 'marginRight' => 1417.322834646, 'marginTop' => 2834.645669291, 'marginBottom' => 1417.322834646)
);
//$html = $_POST['description'];
$html = $_POST['description'];


\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, $html, false, false);

// Save file
// Saving the document as OOXML file...
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
//$objWriter->save('test.docx');


  $temp_file_uri = tempnam('', 'xyz');
  $objWriter->save($temp_file_uri);
 //download code
  header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
  header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=helloWorld.docx');
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Expires: 0');
  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($temp_file_uri));
  readfile($temp_file_uri);
  unlink($temp_file_uri); // deletes the temporary file
  exit;
```

Comment: It is almost certainly a very bad idea to be trying to generate complex XML like this via printing strings. PHP has perfectly good XML classes built in, and there are libraries available like [this one](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) that can read and write OOXML format.

Comment: You are totally right, I'm already reading phpword docs in order to implement it. Meanwhile I need just to add margins to the generated .doc in this script.

Comment: Following @Spudley advice I implemented PHPword. It works totally fine.